# In django serializers can JSONField handle dictionary with mixed type values?

Tags: json, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

There is a Django model and a corresponding rest_framework serializer with a field of type json.

```
from jsonfield.fields importJSONField

class Data(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(null=True)
    detail = JSONField(null=True)

class DataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True)
    detail = serializers.JSONField(required=False, allow_null=True)
```

During insertion of data to the model, error is thrown.
`ERROR invalid input syntax for integer: "Sample"
LINE 3: ...AY['id', 'name'], ARRAY[1, 'Sample']...`

If the data for the `detail` field is `{'id':1, 'name': 'Sample'}`. If the data is changed to `{'id':'1', 'name': 'Sample'}`, this error is not there.

Is there a way to handle the data when it is `{'id':1, 'name': 'Sample'}`? Is there a better type for the `detail` field or should the field be modified?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to replicate the error.

Just to be sure, you're connecting to a Postgres database and are using the built-in JSONfield? The database is clean and migrations are all applied?

The following works just fine for me when POSTing a json payload, via the DRF browsable UI, to create a new model

**Media type:** application/json

**Content:**

```
{
    "title": "test data",
    "detail": {"id":1, "name": "Sample"}
}
```

**settings.py**

```
# ... 

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': '', # snipped
        'USER': '', # snipped
        'PASSWORD': '', # snipped
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from drfsandpit.restapi import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'data', views.DataViewSet)
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

from .models import Data
from .serializers import DataSerializer

class DataViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Data.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DataSerializer
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Data


class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True)
    detail = serializers.JSONField(required=False, allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = ('title', 'detail')
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField


class Data(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(null=True)
    detail = JSONField(null=True)
```

Comment: Changed name, still same issue.

Comment: Dang. I’m gonna try replicate this when Im back at keyboard tomorrow.